# Remove variables with factor level 1

Tags: r

I am using the program `gs` in the `bnlearn` package for my data frame `EMGbin`. The dataframe `EMGbin` contains all factors, ranging from A to Z. `EMGbin` has 600000 columns and 130 rows. Here is a sample of `EMGbin`:

```
   V101  V102  V103  V104  V105  V106
 1    L     M     D     S     O     O
 2    L     M     C     P     A     O
 3    J     M     C     O     O     O
 4    L     N     D     R     A     O
 5    K     M     D     O     A     O
 6    K     M     C     P     O     O
 7    K     N     D     Q     O     O
 8    L     N     D     R     O     O
 9    L     M     D     O     O     O
10    K     M     D     S     A     O
```

When I run the program `gs(EMGbin)`, I get the error:

`Error in check.data(x) : all factors must have at least two levels.`

When I run `sapply(EMGbin, nlevels)`, I see the levels of factors each of the 600,000 variables has, and I see some of them are listed as 1 level. Would removing the variables with 1 factor level help? So far, the only way I know how to do this is `x[, sapply(x, fun) != 1]`, but I don't know what to substitute in for `fun`.

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
x[, sapply(x, nlevels) > 1]
```

Comment: if you also have variables that are not factors, and want to keep them: `x[, (sapply(x, nlevels>1)) | (sapply(x, is.factor)==FALSE)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can check the number of levels in a factor with the `nlevels` function.

Comment: When I use `nlevels("A")`, I get back 0. Same for if I use `nlevels("O")` and all other letters

Comment: `nlevels` takes a `factor` argument.  Try `nlevels(EMGbin$V105)`.

Comment: `nlevels(EMGbin$V105)` returns 3. Does that mean for the values where `nlevels(EMGbin$COLNAME)` returns 1, I need to delete the column to make it work?

Comment: You already had most of the answer.  You want `x[, sapply(x, fun) != 1]`, and you need to substitute `nlevels` for `fun`.